# JQuery: how to find links on a page that start with http or https in one selector?

Tags: jquery

I am able to find links start with either http or https as follows:

```
$("a[href^='http']")
```

or

```
$("a[href^='https']")
```

How can find links that start with either http or https in one selector? $("a[href^='http|https']") seems not working.

Thanks!

Comment: `$("a[href^='http']")` would find both since https also starts with http

Comment: You are really smart!

Comment: Ah right you want to find them distinctly I misread :D

Comment: But your solution works too. We only have http or https protocol, right? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("a[href^='http']")` will find both since https starts with http.

You could also use `$("a[href^='http:'],a[href^='https:']")` if you wanted to make sure it didn't start with something like `httpfordummies.com`

Answer (score 1):

`$("a[href^='https']")` for https

`$("a[href^='http']").not("[href^='https']")` for http

Comment: Thanks for chiming in!